Is there a function available to convert HIGHS solution file format to GLPK solution file format?
I am currently using HIGHS to solve a mps file and get a solution file using the following code:
import highspy

h = highspy.Highs()
filename = 'abc.mps'
h.readModel(filename)

h.setOptionValue("solver","ipm")

h.run()

h.writeSolution("abc_highs_solution.sol", 1)

The solution file format of HIGHS looks as shown below. It has two different sections for columns and rows:

I need to get the solution into the GLPK solution file format which is as shown. It also has two sections for rows and columns.

Is there a functionality available to convert the HIGHS solution file to the GLPK solution file format?
